# Circle Avatar radius property not working

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put a CircleAvatar inside appbar leading:

```
//appbar
 return AppBar(
    leading: userInfo() 
    ...

StreamBuilder userInfo() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
    initialData: null,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final User user = snapshot.data;
          final photoUrl = user.photoURL;
          return CircleAvatar(
            radius: 16.0,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photoUrl),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          );
        }
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
```

but no matter what radius i set, it doesn't change.
How could i decrease the CircleAvatar radius in this case?

[CircleAvatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPNaL.png)

Comment: Do you find any solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it with a FittedBox then set the fit parameter to Boxfit.cover

```
return AppBar(
    leading: userInfo() 
    ...

StreamBuilder userInfo() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: _auth.authStateChanges(),
    initialData: null,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final User user = snapshot.data;
          final photoUrl = user.photoURL;
          return FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 16.0,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(photoUrl),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),);
        }
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the circle avatar with a column

```
 Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 15,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```